# Gradle Scala Plugin corollary to addCompilerPlugin in sbt

Tags: scala, gradle, scala-macros

What is the best way to add a Scala compiler plugin to the scalaCompile task in Gradle?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Add a configuration for compiler plugins:

   `configurations {
     scalaCompilerPlugin
   }`
2. Add compiler plugin dependencies:

   `dependencies {
     scalaCompilerPlugin "org.scalamacros:paradise_2.11.7:2.1.0"
   }`
3. Set up the option:

   `tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
     scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = [
       "-Xplugin:" + configurations.scalaCompilerPlugin.asPath
     ]
   }`

I was able to [use Macro Paradise in a Gradle-built project](https://github.com/vergenzt/rtm-scala/blob/e2c0ee4bfe21006d15b09acdcf1236153a16b32f/build.gradle#L38-L44) with this setup.

Comment: wondering if you can help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594587/how-do-you-cross-compile-to-scala-js-with-gradle