# How do you Cross Compile to Scala.JS with Gradle

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle, dependency-management, scala.js

When adding Scala.JS dependencies in SBT you use `%%%`. E.g.

`libraryDependencies += "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.9.0"`

How is this done in the Gradle Scala plugin?

Comment: Can't really write a full answer, right now, but you should use the Scala.js Gradle pluging: https://github.com/gtache/scalajs-gradle

Comment: Great! thanks for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%%% = the scala version + scalajs version. So something like:

```
val scalaJsDomV = "0.9.1"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % scalaJsDomV
)
```

would be

```
compile "org.scala-js:scalajs-dom_sjs0.6_2.12:0.9.1"
```

Or if you used the ext for multiple used versions it would be something like:

```
ext {
    versions = [
        js: 'sjs0.6', 
        major: '2.12', // major scala version
    ]
    versions['scala'] = versions.major + '.2'
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "org.scala-js:scalajs-dom_${versions.js}_${versions.major}:0.9.1"
}
```

Note that there is also a plugin that can help with scalajs: https://github.com/gtache/scalajs-gradle

Comment: https://github.com/gtache/scalajs-gradle appears to be dead - the last commit was three years ago.

Comment: I don't think it works, it will only compile into java class(es) instead of the intended javascript file, which is useless