# How does one combine ScalaFXML with Gradle?

Tags: scala, gradle, scalafx

Let me set up my end goal first:
I want to build a scala only gui application, that I can design with [scene builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) and later port with [gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/) to any platform I want to.

I was able to find out, that one needs to use [JavaFXPorts](https://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/javafxports/) in Scala to make that happen. I also found out that I need to use gradle to apply gluon successfully, or so it seems (please correct me if I am wrong because that's where the headache starts)

**So in short that means: ScalaFXML and Gradle need to work together, but how?**

I've found some interesting projects, but sadly none of these hit my criteria just right:

- [This](https://github.com/rladstaetter/fx-tictactoe) one used JavaFX instead of ScalaFX
- [This](https://github.com/voxoid0/scala-javafx-desktop-android-ios) one added Java to the project instead of using pure scala

After a long time searching I found a [project](https://github.com/scalafx/ScalaFX-Tutorials/tree/master/scalafxml-example), that was almost right. Sadly, this was built in sbt and not in gradle.
None the less I used that project as a base/example, as this was the first to use [sfxml](https://github.com/vigoo/scalafxml) in way that was easily understood.

I have a gradle script, that almost works

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        // during build, we depend on the jfxmobile-plugin
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.10'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'scala'
    id 'application'
}
apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

configurations {
    scalaCompiler
    scalaCompilerPlugin
}
configurations.scalaCompiler.transitive = false


compileScala.targetCompatibility = "1.8"


mainClassName = 'sfxml.Main'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.6'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.6'

    compile 'com.gluonhq:particle:1.1.3'

    compile group: 'org.scalafx', name: 'scalafx_2.12', version: '8.0.144-R12'
    compile group: 'org.scalafx', name: 'scalafxml-core-sfx8_2.12', version: '0.4'
    compile group: 'org.scalamacros', name: 'paradise_2.12.6', version: '2.1.1'

    scalaCompiler "org.scalamacros:paradise_2.12.6:2.1.1"

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = [
            "-Xplugin:" + configurations.scalaCompilerPlugin.asPath,
            "-Ymacro-debug-lite"
    ]
    options.compilerArgs = ["-Xdebug", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=9999"]
}
```

After finally finding all the right repositories (or so I thought) no errors were marked down during the import process from IDEA, but at last I got the following error:

```
Error:(10, 7) macro annotation could not be expanded (the most common reason for that is that you need to enable the macro paradise plugin; another possibility is that you try to use macro annotation in the same compilation run that defines it)
class AdoptionFormPresenter(private val sizeTextField: TextField,
```

But as you might have figured out - if you've read the gradle script - I already tried enabling the plugin. So how do I fix this and achieve the goal stated at the beginning?

Btw: I already found the following solutions, but those also didn't work

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086241/enabling-the-macro-paradise-scala-compiler-plugin-in-maven-projects) uses maven, but I want to use gradle, soo... thx google?
- [This](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-apply-scala-macro-paradise-plugin/9316) sadly doesn't work
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439912/gradle-scala-plugin-corollary-to-addcompilerplugin-in-sbt) sadly... also does not work :/

Footnote: All SDKs are freshly downloaded at the time of this posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after revisiting my gradle script and checking against the previously mentioned work arrounds, I found my mistake.

I didn't include the complete answer from [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-apply-scala-macro-paradise-plugin/9316/5). So after editing my build.gradle to only include the necessary things, I got the following:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'scala'
}
apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

configurations {
    scalaCompiler
}
configurations.scalaCompiler.transitive = false


compileScala.targetCompatibility = "1.8"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.6'

    compile group: 'org.scalafx', name: 'scalafx_2.12', version: '8.0.144-R12'
    compile group: 'org.scalafx', name: 'scalafxml-core-sfx8_2.12', version: '0.4'

    scalaCompiler "org.scalamacros:paradise_2.12.6:2.1.1"

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

def String scalaCompilerOptions="-Xplugin:$configurations.scalaCompiler.singleFile.path"
compileScala.scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = [scalaCompilerOptions]
compileTestScala.scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = [scalaCompilerOptions]
```

That script will run [this project](https://github.com/scalafx/ScalaFX-Tutorials/tree/master/scalafxml-example/src/main/scala/sfxml) with gradle instead of sbt.

Side note:
If you get the error "Cannot load resource: AdoptionForm.fxml" read the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361212/where-do-i-put-my-resources-in-scala)

I didn't complete my previously stated goal just yet, since I haven't used gluon for now. But the main problem of this post is solved, so I will mark this as the right answer.

I might add the gluon integration later if I get it to work.